# How to ignore checkstyle on methods according to a specific pattern

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is there a way for the checkstyle rule `MethodLength` to set a pattern for methods to be ignored? I want to suppress the checkstyle rule for all methods named `getMetaInformation()`.

Other checkstyle rules like `LineLength` have the property

`<property name="ignorePattern" value=""/>`

but this seems not to be available for the `MethodLength`rule (see http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/sizes/MethodLengthCheck.html).

Comment: Are you bound to some particular Checkstyle version? I could implement it and you'll be able to use it whenever next version is released.

Comment: Wow, that would be great! I'm not bound to a specific version. Should I create a new feature request?

Comment: Please do, I can start implementing it tonight

Comment: Done: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3376 Thank you in advance for your effort! Maybe you could answer this question as soon as the new release is available, so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Sure! Can you answer question in  http://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3376?

Comment: @MichalKordas do you need more information on github issue?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there is no way to do this by Check config http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#MethodLength , you need to use suppressions/filters to do this.

Comment: I didnt find a way with suppression filters; they seem to only allow patterns for filenames, and fixed column / row positions. Do you have an example?